# How to inline in javascript

Tags: ajax

this sample code below that i want to inline..

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#secSubmit').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'process/process_mst.php?action=supplier_create',
         data: "sec_supplier=" + $('#sec_supplier').val() + "&sec_branch=" + $('#sec_branch').val() 
         + "&sec_dmorigin=" + $('#sec_dmorigin').val() + "&sec_dmnum=" + $('#sec_dmnum').val() 
         + "&sec_amount=" + $('#sec_amount').val() + "&sec_desc=" + $('#sec_desc').val()
         + "&sec_user_id=" + $('#sec_user_id').val(),
         success: function(data){
         error = '';
         if($('#sec_supplier').val() == "")                 
             error += ' - Please select supplier';
         if($('#sec_branch').val() == "")                   
         error += ' - Please select branch';

         if(error != '')
    alert(error);
    else{
    alert("Data inserted...");
    window.location = "support_entry.php";
         }
       }
     });            
    });             
  });
</script>
```

It display like this:

```
- Please select supplier - Please select branch
```

I want the display to be like this:

```
-Please select supplier </br>
-Please select branch </br>
```

Comment: did you try changing the HTML that you append?

Comment: *sidenote:* although you should use `\n` in this case, the correct syntax of a HTML line break tag is `<br />` or `<br>`, depends on which DOCTYPE you use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "\n" character to do a line jump in a alert box.

For example:

```
error += ' - Please select supplier'+"\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
if($('#sec_supplier').val() == "")                 
      error += " - Please select supplier \n";
if($('#sec_branch').val() == "")                   
      error += " - Please select branch \n";
```

You should be using `\n` for line break